# javascript find object in object-array though specific object property

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, typescript

I have an array of thread objects like this

```
threadlist:Thread[]= [thread{id:1},thread{id:2},thread{id:3},...]
```

I also have a ThreadRelation array inside a user object like below to store if the user has a certain thread bookmarked or not.
Please note that the id in Thread does not match its place in the array.

```
user{
  user_id:number,...(some other user typical properties)
  threadRelations:ThreadRelation[]=[
  threadRelation{
    id:2,//relates to id property of a Thread object
    isBookmarked:true
  },
  threadRelation{
    id:18,
    isBookmarked:true
  },..
]}
```

I want to create a function which returns an array with only bookmarked threads of a user. I can achieve this using two for-loops and if-statements, but i don't think its efficient..
Is there some methods where i can find that specific object inside the array directly?

```
updateBookmarkedList(){
      for (var i = 0; i < this.activeUser.threadsRelation.length; i++){
        if ( this.activeUser.threadsRelation[i].bookmarked == true){
          var searchId = this.activeUser.threadsRelation[i].id;
          for (var j = 0; j < this.threadlist.length; j++){
            if (this.threadlist[j].id == searchId){
              this.userBookmarkedList.push(this.threadlist[j])
            }
          }
        }
      }
  }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)! A side note, your JSON is invalid, unless this is pseudo code. In which case, you should provide a full example of what you have (with valid data).

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Consider making this an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Thread.id` is a unique identifier, then you really should use a `Map` instead of an `Array` of objects with no keys. Without keys you will have to iterate the arrays with no other choices.

When iterating an `Array`, try to use built in iteration methods like `forEach`. They are more efficient and looks neater than loops.

To make a supplement to [@Tamas-Hegedus's answer using ES6 `iterator` feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36452972/902036), I created a JSFiddle using current version of JavaScript to make a "Array-Map", you can replace it with `Map` if `Thread.id` is not numeric.

See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dz902/y8aew84f/).

Answer (score 1):

With [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), you can keep only the bookmarked thread relationships. From this filtered list, you can build a list of threads based off of the `id` criteria.

```js
var threads = [
  { id: 1 },
  { id: 2 },
  { id: 3 }
];

var users = [{
  user_id: 1,
  threadRelations: [
    { id: 2,  isBookmarked: true },
    { id: 18, isBookmarked: true }
  ]
}];

var userBookmarkedList = updateBookmarkedList(users[0], threads);
document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>Threads -> ' + JSON.stringify(userBookmarkedList, null, 2) + '</pre>';

function updateBookmarkedList(user, threads) {
  return user.threadRelations.filter(function(threadRelation) {
    return threadRelation.isBookmarked === true;
  }).reduce(function(list, threadRelation) {
    return list.concat(threads.filter(function(thread) {
      return thread.id === threadRelation.id;
    }));
  }, []);
}
```

You could also create a map, to improve lookup performance.

```js
var threads = [
  { id: 1 },
  { id: 2 },
  { id: 3 }
];

var users = [{
  user_id: 1,
  threadRelations: [
    { id: 2,  isBookmarked: true },
    { id: 18, isBookmarked: true }
  ]
}];

var threadMap           = mapBy(threads, 'id');
var userBookmarkedList  = retrieveBookmarkedThreads(users[0], threadMap);
document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>Threads -> ' + JSON.stringify(userBookmarkedList, null, 2) + '</pre>';

function mapBy(list, key) {
  return list.reduce(function(map, item) {
    map[item[key]] = item;
    return map;
  }, {});
}

function retrieveBookmarkedThreads(user, threadMap) {
  return user.threadRelations.filter(function(threadRelation) {
    return threadRelation.isBookmarked === true;
  }).reduce(function(list, threadRelation) {
    return (function(thread) {
      return thread != null ? list.concat(thread) : list;
    }(threadMap[threadRelation.id]));
  }, []);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you keep a map of the "threads" by their id?

To create the map from the array:

```
var threadsById = new Map(threads.map(t => [t.id, t]));
```

To get if a threadid is present:

```
if (threadsById.has(threadRelation.id)) {
  ...
}
```

To get the thread by its id:

```
var currentThread = threadsById.get(threadRelation.id);
```